# Compile-Time Error When Navigating Between Pages C++/WinRT Windows App SDK

Tags: c++-winrt, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have been trying for a long time to get page navigation to work in a Windows App SDK C++/WinRT-based app, to no avail. I have two pages and I'm trying to navigate from Page 1 to Page 2 via code-behind in an event handler. I have tried embedding a `Frame` within Page 1's `Window` and then using that to call something like `myFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<...>());` and I have tried using the following code:

```cpp
Frame rootFrame{ nullptr };
auto content = Window::Current().Content();
if (content) rootFrame = content.try_as<Frame>();
rootFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<...>());
```

Which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/xaml-typename).

They all produce the same error:

```
WMC9999 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xaml.XamlType' to type 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.Compiler.DirectUI.DirectUIXamlType'
```

Software Versions:

- `Windows App SDK 1.1.0-preview3`
- `Windows SDK Build Tools 10.0.22000.194`
- `CppWinRT 2.0.210806.1`
- `Windows ImplementationLibrary 1.0.211019.2`
- `Visual Studio 2022`

Comment: The `System.` namespace is used by the .NET projections exclusively. Does your project somehow reference .NET?

Comment: It references `Microsoft.Windows.System` and others, but those are all "Unresolved References". See [this image](https://i.imgur.com/u7D8usL.png).

Comment: There is no `Xaml` namespace under `Microsoft.Windows.System`. This is a different `System.` namespace. We can safely preclude the SDK, C++/WinRT, and WIL from the problem space. Now, both the Windows App SDK and the Visual Studio teams have support channels. Have you asked them for feedback, provided that you have a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I have not asked them yet. Would you mind pointing me to their respective support channels? I'll work on a minimal reproducible example in the mean time. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Actually, I think the issue is with creating new pages. If I add a [new item] `Blank Page (C++/WinRT)` it has the error I'm getting. I didn't edit anything in the new page.

Comment: Github channel for Winui3 and windows app sdk: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml

Answer (score 1):

In the idl file you need to change Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page to Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page.

The tooling is a little under cooked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDp0X.png)